# Index out of range error when comparing elements in list

Tags: python, list, indexing, tuples, range

I want to create a simple program in python that returns my name or print 'error' if it's not my name.
It's basic. Like, I want to give this list:

```
(('Leonardo',), ('Leonardo',), ('Leonardo',), ('Leonardo',), ('Leonardo',), ('Leonardo',), ('Leonardo',), ('Leonardo',), ('Leonardo',), ('Leonardo',), ('0122',), ('0122',), ('0122',), ('0122',), ('0122',))
```

and then check all the elements and if the word inside them are `Leonardo`, then it should print `error`. Can anyone help me?

I tried this, but it gives me list index out of range:

```
 for i in range(len(resultado)):
     if list(resultado[i])[i] == 'Leonardo':
         print('erro')
```

Comment: resultado = the name of the list

Comment: You want to do a nested loop to iterate over the contents of the inner list. Currently you're accessing, for example, index 2 of the list, yielding ('Leonardo',). Then, trying to get index 2 of this list yields out of bounds, since there is only 1 value.

Comment: Try if resultado[i][0] == 'Leonardo': (assuming resultado is the name of the list).  This checks the first element of each sublist.

Comment: `for i in range(len(resultado))` where you don't actually use `i` for anything except to pull out one element at a time is just pretzel logic. You want simply `for item in resultado` to loop over the items in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to cycle through each list inside the list.
Another way to do this would be:

```
for i in resultado:
    for a in i:
       if "Leonardo" in a:
            print("Leonardo")
       else:
            print("error")
```

Also, please be a little more clear with instructions as the instructions say "*I want to create a simple program in python that returns my name or print 'error' if it's not my name.*" But then right after you say "*if the word inside them are Leonardo, then it should print error.*" Do you want the program to print error if it is not your name or if it is? Other than that, happy coding! (P.S. You cannot return your name unless it is in a function)

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace:

```
if list(resultado[i])[i] == 'Leonardo':
```

with:

```
if resultado[i][0] == 'Leonardo':
```

Since you're checking the first element only.

Comment: Conversely, `if list(resultado[i][0]) == ['Leonardo']:` would also work, though of course converting both sides to a list is completely wasteful, but helps highlight how exactly this was wrong. Also `if list(resultado[i][0])[0]`converts the first element to a list, then extracts the first element from that list (-: but the proper solution is probably to have an actual list, not a tuple of tuples, and simply check `if 'Leonardo' in that_list`

Answer (score 1):

The input you present is not actually a list; it is a tuple of tuples.

Depending on how exactly you ended up with this structure, you would probably like to end up in a situation where you have

```
resultado_list = ['Leonardo', 'Leonardo', 'Leonardo', ...]
```

instead of the current nested structure.  Then you can simply say

```
if 'Leonardo' in resultado_list:
```

To convert the current structure, assuming it's uniform, you can say

```
resultado_list = [r[0] for r in resultado]
```

This simply discards any values other than the first from each nested tuple; but again, the data you present shows that no tuple has more than a single element. Though more likely, whatever code created the nested structure in the first place should be fixed to return a single list without nesting.

If you really want to keep the original structure, you can of course also say

```
if ('Leonardo',) in resultado:
```

The error in your attempt is that you try to examine `resultado[0][0]` (works fine), `resultado[1][1]` (fails, because there is no second element), `resultado[2][2]` (ditto) etc. The trivial fix is to change `resultado[i][i]` to `resultado[i][0]`; but as outlined above, there are many improvements you could make over this.

If you are checking whether all the elements are `'Leonardo'` that would be

```
if all(r[0] == 'Leonardo' for r in resultado):
    print('all Leonardos!')
else:
    print('erro')
```

for the original structure, and

```
if all(r == 'Leonardo' for r in resultado_list): ...
```

for the flattened, proper list representation.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's a nested tuple you only loop the first layer and get the first element of the nested tuple. So you use [i] for the first index and [0] for the second.

Therefore instead of

```
list(resultado[i])[i]
```

You should use

```
resultado[i][0]
```